# Undefined local variable or method when I use <%= home_index_path %> in application.js.erb, why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

As the title states, I have an application.js.erb file that looks like the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require html5shiv
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#opening-first").fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $("#opening-second").fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $("#opening-container").delay(500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $("#body-overlay").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
  });

  $(".me").on('click', function(){
    fadeAndReload('<%= me_home_index_path %>');
  });

  $(".home").on('click', function(){
    fadeAndReload('<%= root_path %>');
  });

  function fadeAndReload(fileName) {
    var body = $("#reload-me");
    body.fadeOut(500, function() {
        body.load(fileName, function() {
        body.fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

My routes are listed as:

```
   home_index GET /home/index(.:format) home#index
me_home_index GET /home/me(.:format)    home#me
         root     /                     home#index
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `me_home_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f99d63b5728>:0x007f99d65ef9d0>
  (in /Users/[filepathhere]/javascripts/application.js.erb)
```

What is the problem??

Comment: Did you restart Rails?

Comment: Yes I did. This is development though so caching shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I had to add this line to the top of my application.js.erb file under my require statements, and everything works properly now:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_
helpers } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `me_home_index_path` on `me_home_index_url`
Wish it will help.